# Blender And use of SGA texture

Tags: texturing

Hello Forum people I have a combination of three textures here, I understand two of them, one is a diffuse color map and the other is a Normal map, but the Blue one here is titled SGA. I think it's a roughness map? but I really have no idea. would anyone here know what this texture is and how to use it properly with nodes in blender cycles render?

[image]
[image]
[image]

[[image][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWLav.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Aint no clue.
Any information about the source of the teture? This might help

Comment: So looking at the Face, it looks like it's also named SG, but it's called SGO. not SGA? and when i apply them the same way as the body, there is a very visible seam between the two pieces, so I don't think O is the same as A, I'm sorry this is confusing, cause it certainly is to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably 3 separate grayscale textures combined into an RGB image file so red, green and blue channels are separate textures:

[image]

The blue one looks like it might be ambient occlusion, but it's hard to tell. So the A in SGA might be for ambient occlusion, but why A why not AO?.. Well, we should ask the person who created this. Anyway, red looks like it might be specular and green seems like glossiness(inverse of roughness).

To use them, just split the channels using Separate Color node and use the outputs of it as any other textures whatever way you want. So it might look something like this, if you want to use Principled BSDF:

[image]

It's worth noting that this is evidently not a very smart way to name textures if they are meant to be distributed because it causes precisely this kind of confusion. So if you ever find yourself in a situation where you have to create assets for other people to use, just remember this and give the files proper descriptive names.

Comment: Wow I think you are 100% right, thank you very much for taking the time to respond in such detail, I will try it out in blender, thank you! I think I marked your answer correctly.

Comment: Would you have a suggestion what color space i should set the normal map to? it seems setting it to RGB color space produces strange seams on it. but setting it to non color gives a better result?

Comment: Non-color is the usual setting for normal maps. Since it's not color information and should not go through any color management at all.